# Проверка сайта на уязвимость.

Tags: безопасность

Сделал сайт на localhost'e. Собираюсь выкладывать на хостинг.
Как можно провести проверку сайта на взломоустойчивость и т.д?
Есть ли какие-нибудь сервисы для этого?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого есть специальный фреймворк, называется он [W3AF](http://w3af.sourceforge.net/). Это очень классная штука для веб пентестинга. Там имеется куча всяких полезных фич для тестинга своих веб приложений. По сути, W3AF - это платформа, которая сама по себе не несет особых функций для тестировщика, но к платформе можно привинтить плагины, количество которых уже перевалило за 100. Плагины для тестирования созданы разные(кстати, создавать плагины может каждый =) ): от поиска банальных дыр в SQL-запросах (SQL-Injection) и критических GET-запросов до расщепления HTTP-запроса ([HTTP Response Splitting](http://www.xakep.ru/post/24084/)). Так, что флаг вам в руки и вперед, тестить приложение!

Comment: для тестинга(не в коем случае для взлома других сайтов) на SQL injection рекомендую SQLmap

Comment: Поверьте, набор плагинов данного фреймворка  содержит штучки, которые похлеще sqlmap`а.

Самое главное, что плагины можно комбинировать и "бомбить" сайт по определенным уязвимым точкам.

Comment: просто с ним я имел дело, и поверьте, его возможностей в плане инъекций более чем достаточно, он кроссплатформенный(написан на Python), легок в использовании и специализируется в узкой области, а как известно узкоспециализированные вещи эффективнее универсальных